# Install CUDA toolkit in non-nvidia hardware

Tags: software-installation, cuda

How do I install cuda toolkit for a pc having no Nvidia cards?

I want to run cuda programs on CPU.

My Graphics: Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, here is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087361/gpu-emulator-for-cuda-programming-without-the-hardware).

However, I still suggest you to get a Nvidia card if you want to run something real on it.